# orderby meta_value_num is not working, giving default order

Tags: php, wp-query

I am trying to order my posts by a meta value so that I can show the most popular posts. But it is returning the latest posts instead.

```
//WordPress loop for the custom post type
        $popular_args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'games',
            'posts_per_page'    => 6,
            'suppress_filters'  => true, //Just in case something else is interfaring.
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_key'          => 'view_54ygtt',
            'order'             => 'DESC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                      'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                )
            ),
        );
        $popular_query = new WP_Query($popular_args);
        while ($popular_query->have_posts()) : $popular_query->the_post();

            //Get the template
            echo get_the_title() .' - '. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'view_54ygtt', true) .'<br>';
    
        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**Result:**

Sample Post 6 - 1282

Sample Post 5 - 25719

Sample Post 4 - 88999

Sample Post 3 - 77354

Sample Post 2 - 7948

Sample Post 1 - 1526

**It should be:**

Sample Post 4 - 88999

Sample Post 3 - 77354

Sample Post 5 - 25719

Sample Post 2 - 7948

Sample Post 1 - 1526

Sample Post 6 - 1282

Comment: You could just use the `meta_type` arg, but anyway, what does `var_dump( $popular_query->request );` output? And note that you don't need to call `wp_reset_query()` because it's used to reset the **main** query, but your code isn't altering it, so you just need to restore the `$post` global by calling `wp_reset_postdata()` *instead*. Also, I don't see where you defined `$post`, but I presumed `$post->ID` did contain the correct post ID?

Comment: Here is the dump: https://pastebin.com/ZWXmMmd5

`$post` is a global variable that doesn't have to be defined. yes $post->ID contains correct post id or I would get only one post name 6 times.

I am trying to add the code in a custom taxonomy archive `taxonomy-genres.php`

Comment: The query seems to be working on home.php but not in taxonomy-genres.php

Comment: Remember that we shouldn't make unnecessary `WP_Query` calls on archive-based pages, but if you're just trying to display a post list in a separate section on the page, then that's fine. Now instead of using `meta_query`, try replacing that with this: `'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC'` and see what the dump outputs. If it's still not sorting correctly, then try `var_dump( get_posts( $popular_args ) );` (with the same `meta_type`) - if even that didn't sort correctly, then maybe you should try deactivating plugins and see if it helps. Also, what's the code in your `taxonomy-genres.php` file?

Comment: I am trying to make a custom taxonomy archive page that looks and feels like a landing page. The code works perfectly fine on the homepage. both with `meta_type` and `meta_query` I have no idea why it is not working on this archive page.

Comment: Just because it worked on the homepage, it doesn't mean you're doing it properly, so what's the full template code? Have you tried deactivating plugins? Does your theme have any (custom) code which hooks on `pre_get_posts` or another hooks applied by the `WP_Query` class?

Comment: @SallyCJ I have found the problem. It has nothing to do with The query. I suspected that there was something going on with the theme and sure enough, we had a `pre_get_post` filter in the function.php to show modified posts first in archive pages. I've excluded taxonomy archives from there and it is working correctly. Anyway, can we override pre_get_post rules for a specific `wp_query()`?

Comment: The `'suppress_filters' => true` should work in normal cases, so I don't why in your case that didn't work. But if you could show the offending code (both the `add_action()` or maybe `add_filter()` call, and the callback), I might be able to tell you why. And in most cases, if the `request` property/value doesn't look good, then it generally means the active theme or a plugin is filtering the query, but not necessarily via the `pre_get_posts` hook.